# Help identifying a tree

Tags: identification, trees

A couple of years ago, during a holidays in Segovia (Spain), I picked some seeds from a couple of trees.
I sowed them and eventually, some baby trees were born.
I wonder if some of you knows what kind of tree they are.
You can see them in Google Maps:
https://www.google.es/maps/@40.9493991,-4.1259099,3a,38.4y,6h,104.32t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sKweY1Wbj4qFQs6SXAm_U6g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

[image: Grown up trees]

(The brown "leaves" in the branches are some paper-like tulips which have the seeds inside)
And one of those I planted so you can see the leaves  (We are in a heat wave and my plants are a little bit sad!):

[image: Baby tree]

Any clues? Thanks!

**Edit:**
Good news! I moved these to larger pots and pruned them, and they are growing greener and happier. Thanks you all for the advices!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your plants are 'sad' because the one in the image is in a tiny, tiny pot - if you know this plant wants to be a tree, you need to pot on regularly to enable it to develop the roots it needs. As for what it is, do you know what colour and form the flowers were on the original trees? Do you have a close up image of the mature trees shown in the main photo? When did you take the photo, as in which month?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Bamboo. I know I need to move it to a larger pot (I've been myself moving from one house to another and it was easier to move smaller pots instead of larger ones). I have no idea on how are the flowers, and also no images of the mature tree. The image of the trees was taken in september, according to Google (I was there in august and the "paper tulips" were quite similar, maybe more yellow instead of brown)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From its protruding inflorescence, this tree makes me think of [*Koelreuteria Paniculata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koelreuteria_paniculata).

Here is a close-up if it is the one, where you see the lantern-like fruits:
[image]

- > about the drying  leaves:

Agreed with Bamboo, offer bigger pots to the little ones.

Comment: That makes sense. I've googled for "Koelreuteria Segovia", and apparently the gardeners in Segovia have planted that kind of tree in some streets and squares, so it's quite likely that those are Koelreuteria too.  Thanks!